# Python decode list elements from utf16

Tags: python, decode, utf-16

I have problem with reading list created from text file opened by python. This is my code:

```
if orderFilesListCount >= 1:
     orderContents = list()
     with open(os.path.join(directory,fileName), "r") as f:
          for line in f:
               orderContents.append(line)
```

orderContents looks like (this is just passage for demonstration purposes):

```
'\x000\x001\x005\x00 \x006\x003\x00 \x005\x003\x00 \x004\x004\x00\n', '\x00\n', '\x00'
```

I think that it is utf-16 but when I try to decode list string by string I get following error (as I understant it is impossible to decode str object):

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

What should I do? Am I getting it wrong? Maybe it is not utf-16?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, decoding `str`ings doesn't make sense because they have already been decoded. However, one can decode `bytes`:

```
with open(os.path.join(directory,fileName), "rb") as f:  # open as binary
    data = f.read().decode("utf16")
```